# how to detect if a request is ajax or normal on server side

Tags: ajax, jquery

im using jquery to make ajax requests. is it possible to detect if the request is an ajax request or a normal request on the server side? does jquery add any input variables or headers to make this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jQuery seconds an additional header on the request when it's ajax header called `X-Requested-With` with a value of `XMLHttpRequest`.  Check for this header on the request.

Alternatively, set any header you want using `.ajaxSetup` like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {"X-My-Header":"Bob"}
});
```

Comment: FYI, jQuery does *not* set the `X-Requested-With` header for CORS AJAX requests (see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8423). It was removed from CORS requests to prevent the browser from sending unnecessary preflighted `OPTIONS` requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net mvc your controller will have a property IsAjaxRequest
simply check for this property

```
if (IsAjaxRequest) 
{
   // do your stuff and render ajax view
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually on the controller is it? I think its an extension method on the request object. i.e Request.IsAjaxRequest()