# Java Servlet: Best Way to Determine if request is AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest

What is the best way to determine whether a GET or POST request coming into a java servlet is an AJAX request? The method I've come across so far in my search is to strip the information out of the header with

```
"XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
```

Are there other ways to handle this? It seems like relying on the header is not a terribly robust solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect if a request is ajax or normal on server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419223/how-to-detect-if-a-request-is-ajax-or-normal-on-server-side)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP/Servlet How to identify if the HTTP request came from an ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004877/jsp-servlet-how-to-identify-if-the-http-request-came-from-an-ajax-request)

Comment: There is no other reliable method afaik. But what's wrong with the method you posted?

Comment: And yes, it is not a terribly robust solution. If this is in any way important, make Ajax requests go to a separate URL or include extra parameters (and of course, that can still be spoofed).

Comment: Any user-side information can be spoofed so no, there is no fullproof way. I fail to see why one would need to know this though?

Answer (score 3):

Following HTML document uses `jQuery.post()` method to send an asynchronous AJAX request to Servlet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>click demo</title>
  <style>
  body {font-family: verdana;margin:20px; font-size: 14px;}
  div.container {border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f0ffff;padding:10px;width:460px;
  }
  p.result {color:red;font-weight:bold;}
  h3 {color:blue;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myAsyncBtn").click(function() {
        $.post(
                "async",
                function( data ) {
                $(".result").html(data);
                }
        );
    }); 
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Ajax Request Detection using Java</h3>
<p>Click this button to make a Asynchronous Request 
    <button id="myAsyncBtn"> Click Here</button>
</p>
<p>Now click a Link to make a synchronous request 
    <a href="async">Sync Call</a>
</p>
<p class="result"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A Controller which needs to deal with both type of request can use `request.getHeader()` method to detect the Request type. Developer can use `x-requested-with` header parameter to get the request type. In case of Ajax Request `request.getHeader('x-requested-with')` will return `XMLHttpRequest` as String else return `null`.

```
package org.techzoo.async;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/async")
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public AsyncServlet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String headerName = request.getHeader("x-requested-with");

        if(null == headerName){
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String html = "<h3>Clinet send a Synchronous request</h3>" +
                "<p><a href=\"index.jsp\">Go Back</a> to main page</p>";
            out.write(html);
        }
        else {
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.print("Ajax Request Detected");
            out.flush();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {"X-My-Header":"Bob"}
});
```

Comment: Please don't just post code; explain what it does and why you think this is the right solution.

Comment: A Controller which need to deal with both type of request can use request.getHeader() method to detect the Request type. Developer can use x-requested-with header parameter to get the request type. In case of Ajax Request request.getHeader('x-requested-with') will return XMLHttpRequest as string else return null.

Comment: You can click "edit" on your answer to improve it.  But your comment discusses the `X-Requested-With` header OP is already using, not your posted solution.